# mysql huge table query optimization group by

Tags: mysql

I have huge table with about 40 million rows (GPS tracker positions), recorded every 10 seconds from multiple devices inside company. I want to select only the first row of every minute, so I used group by. The problem is that the table is growing up every 10 seconds, I've tried almost everything, googled many hours. So I decided to ask a question.

I'm using MySQL 5.7.11 InnoDB pool 50GB, server is Xeon X5650 with 64GB RAM.

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `eventData` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `position` point NOT NULL,
  `speed` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_id` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_m` datetime GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`time` - interval second(`time`) second)) VIRTUAL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

ALTER TABLE `eventData`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `time` (`time`),
  ADD KEY `device_id` (`device_id`,`processed`),
  ADD KEY `time_m` (`time_m`);
```

SQL:

```
SELECT e.time, e.time_m, X(e.position) AS lat, Y(e.position) AS lng
FROM eventData AS e
WHERE
  e.device_id = 86 AND
  e.time BETWEEN '2016-02-29' AND '2016-03-06'
  GROUP BY DAY(e.time),HOUR(e.time),MINUTE(e.time);
```

Explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT e.time, e.time_m, X(e.position) AS lat, Y(e.position) AS lng FROM eventData AS e WHERE   e.device_id = 86 AND   e.time BETWEEN '2016-02-29' AND '2016-03-06'   GROUP BY DAY(e.time),HOUR(e.time),MINUTE(e.time);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys  | key       | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | ref  | time,device_id | device_id | 5       | const | 2122632 |     6.40 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

describe:

```
DESCRIBE eventData;
+------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Field            | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra             |
+------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| id               | bigint(20)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment    |
| position         | point                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                   |
| speed            | decimal(6,2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                   |
| time             | datetime               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                   |
| device_id        | int(9)                 | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                   |
| processed        | tinyint(1)             | NO   |     | 0       |                   |
| time_m           | datetime               | YES  | MUL | NULL    | VIRTUAL GENERATED |
+------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
```

I've tried:

- without group by: ~0.06s
- group by day,hour,minute: ~4.76s
- group by virtual column (time_m): ~4.92s
- group by e.time DIV 500: ~5.02s

I need to achieve better results than 5 seconds. Please help.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Hello, I've included explain and describe table, analyze table command says OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could partition the table. For example by year. This would dramatically increase the performance due to much smaller indexes.
If this is not possible on your environment, try

GROUP BY date_format(e.time,'%d%H%i');

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try composite index (device_id, time)

2) Try to group by virtual field:

```
SELECT MIN(e.time), e.time_m, X(e.position) AS lat, Y(e.position) AS lng
FROM eventData AS e
WHERE
  e.device_id = 86 AND
  e.time BETWEEN '2016-02-29' AND '2016-03-06'
  GROUP BY e.time_m;
```